# loop over all files in folder in R

Tags: r, ape

I would like to import all files from a folder, convert the files and then export them with the same name, but with a different extension. In my specific case I want to convert 150 nexus files (.nex) to fasta files (.fasta)

This is how the code looks if I do it one by one:

```
library(ape)
gen1 <- read.nexus.data("gen1.nex") #import nexus file
write.dna(gen1, file = "./fastas/gen1.fasta", format = "fasta") #export fastafile
```

But now I fail to make a working for-loop to do all 150 files in one run. This is what I tried:

```
library(ape)
filenames = dir(pattern="*.nex")
for (i in filenames){
i <- read.nexus.data(i)
write.dna(i, file = "./fastas/i.fasta", format = "fasta")
}
```

When I run this code, I get only one file named "i.fasta" and not 150 files named gen1.fasta, gen2.fasta, DNAsequence1.fasta, DNAsequence2.fasta, etc. How should I change the for-loop to make it work correct?

Comment: You may need `paste0("./fastas/", i)`

Comment: Or `sprintf("./fastas/%s.fasta", i)`

Comment: thank you both for your comments. With "paste0" I get the error: non-string argument to internal 'paste'; while with sprintf, I get the error: unsupported type

Comment: Yes the issue is that you're rewriting `i` at each iteration. Try `for (i in filenames){dat <- read.nexus.data(i); write.dna(dat, file = sprintf("./fastas/%s.fasta", i), format = "fasta")}`

Comment: wonderful, the script is working. This saves me a lot of time.

Comment: I'll add it as an answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to 1) include the value of `i` inside the character string giving the fasta filename, 2) not rewrite `i` when you're loading your nexus file.

```
library(ape)
filenames = dir(pattern="*.nex")
for (i in filenames){
    dat <- read.nexus.data(i)
    write.dna(dat, file = sprintf("./fastas/%s.fasta", i), format = "fasta")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

solution is quite simple when using paste function:

```
library(ape)
filenames = dir(pattern="*.nex")
for (f in filenames){
  i <- read.nexus.data(f)
  write.dna(i, file = paste0("./fastas/",f,".fasta"), format = "fasta")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

something not stylish, but it works well

```
library(ape)
tmp <- list.files(pattern = "*.nex")
genes <- lapply(tmp, read.nexus.data)
for (i in 1:length(tmp))
  write.dna(genes[[i]], file = paste(tmp[i], ".fasta"), format = "fasta")
```